# Como criar uma view cujo filtro seja baseado na data/hora do momento da consulta?

Tags: mongodb

Nos documentos da collection **lightningStrikes** há um propriedade **datetime**, cujo valor é do tipo ISODate.
A cada minuto entram vários novos documentos nessa collection.

Meu objetivo é criar uma view que retorne sempre os dados dos últimos 20 minutos, como na query:

```
db.lightningStrikes.find({ datetime: { $gte: new Date(new Date() - 1000*60*20) } })
```

Para isso eu rodei o seguinte comando:

```
db.createView(
    "latestLightningStrikes",
    "lightningStrikes",
    [
        { $match: { datetime: { $gte: new Date(new Date() - 1000*60*20) } } }
    ]
)
```

Esse comando cria a view, porém esses objetos `new Date()` foram interpretados no momento da criação, fixando uma data como condição da minha view, conforme pode ser visto ao rodar:

```
db.system.views.find().pretty()

{
    "_id" : "lightning.latestLightningStrikes",
    "viewOn" : "lightningStrikes",
    "pipeline" : [
        {
            "$match" : {
                "datetime" : {
                    "$gte" : ISODate("2017-09-28T19:25:34.410Z")
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

O que eu preciso é que esses objetos `new Date()` sejam interpretados no momento da minha **consulta**, quando eu fizer um `find` na view, e não no momento da criação dela.

Acredito que esse deveria ser o resultado:

```
db.system.views.find().pretty()

{
    "_id" : "lightning.latestLightningStrikes",
    "viewOn" : "lightningStrikes",
    "pipeline" : [
        {
            "$match" : {
                "datetime" : {
                    "$gte" : new Date(new Date() - 1000*60*20)
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia?
Desde já obrigado!